# ServiceStack ORMLite - Can't Infer Relationship (because of DTO name?)

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am modeling a service business that performs multiple services at each visit to a client.  I have a Visit table, a Service table and a link table, VisitService.  I am using this Request DTO in my service to get a list of services for a visit:

```
    [Route("/visits/{visitid}/services", Verbs = "GET")]
    public class ServicesAtVisit : QueryBase<VisitService, ServiceAtVisit>, IJoin<VisitService, My.Namespace.Service> {
    public int VisitId { get; set; }
}
```

ServiceAtVisit is a custom DTO that I'm projecting into.

Because one of my DTOs is a class with the unfortunate name "Service", I have to fully-qualify it in the IJoin because, otherwise, it is ambiguous with ServiceStack.Service.  Now, when I hit the route, I get the error "Could not infer relationship between VisitService and Service".

The interesting thing is that I've got this working with other many-to-many relationships (Client.AssignedStaffMembers, StaffMember.AssignedClients for the tables Client -> ClientStaffMember -> StaffMember) and I can't see anything different.

Is the problem the name of my DTO and the fact that I'm having to fully-qualify it?

Visit:

```
    [Route("/visits", Verbs = "POST")]
public partial class Visit {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int ServiceRequestId { get; set; }
    public string TimeOfDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? PreferredStartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? PreferredEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstVisit { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastVisit { get; set; }
    public bool IncursWeekendFee { get; set; }
    public bool WaiveWeekendFee { get; set; }
    public bool IncursHolidayFee { get; set; }
    public bool WaiveHolidayFee { get; set; }
    public bool IncursLastMinuteSchedulingFee { get; set; }
    public bool WaiveLastMinuteSchedulingFee { get; set; }
    public bool IncursLastMinuteCancellationFee { get; set; }
    public bool WaiveLastMinuteCancellationFee { get; set; }
    public int? StaffMemberId { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CheckInDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? CheckInStaffMemberId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CheckOutDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? CheckOutStaffMemberId { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public ServiceRequest ServiceRequest { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public StaffMember StaffMember { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public List<ServiceAtVisit> ServicesAtVisit { get; set; }
}
```

VisitService:

```
    public partial class VisitService {

    // Workaround for composite key limitation
    public string Id {
        get {
            return this.VisitId.ToString() + "|" + this.ServiceId.ToString();
        }
    }

    public long VisitId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool FeeIsWaived { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public Visit Visit { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
    public partial class Service {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsHourly { get; set; }
    public bool IsMonthly { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public ServicePrice CurrentPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Projecting results into ServiceAtVisit:

```
    public partial class ServiceAtVisit {
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsHourly { get; set; }
    public bool IsMonthly { get; set; }

    public int VisitId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool FeeIsWaived { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please provide the source code of all the tables you're trying to join.

Comment: Code added - thanks for looking Demis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried creating an AutoQuery Service with all the types you've provided under a custom `MyNamespace` and it's working as expected (in the latest of ServiceStack), i.e:

Service definition:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Route("/visits/{VisitId}/services", Verbs = "GET")]
    public class ServicesAtVisit : QueryBase<VisitService, ServiceAtVisit>, 
        IJoin<VisitService, Service>
    {
        public int VisitId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ServiceAtVisit
    {
        public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsHourly { get; set; }
        public bool IsMonthly { get; set; }

        public int VisitId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool FeeIsWaived { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Type definition:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Route("/visits", Verbs = "POST")]
    public partial class Visit
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int ServiceRequestId { get; set; }
        public string TimeOfDay { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? PreferredStartTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? PreferredEndTime { get; set; }
        public bool IsFirstVisit { get; set; }
        public bool IsLastVisit { get; set; }
        public bool IncursWeekendFee { get; set; }
        public bool WaiveWeekendFee { get; set; }
        public bool IncursHolidayFee { get; set; }
        public bool WaiveHolidayFee { get; set; }
        public bool IncursLastMinuteSchedulingFee { get; set; }
        public bool WaiveLastMinuteSchedulingFee { get; set; }
        public bool IncursLastMinuteCancellationFee { get; set; }
        public bool WaiveLastMinuteCancellationFee { get; set; }
        public int? StaffMemberId { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CheckInDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? CheckInStaffMemberId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CheckOutDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? CheckOutStaffMemberId { get; set; }

        //[Ignore]
        //public ServiceRequest ServiceRequest { get; set; }

        //[Ignore]
        //public StaffMember StaffMember { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public List<ServiceAtVisit> ServicesAtVisit { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class VisitService
    {
        // Workaround for composite key limitation
        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.VisitId.ToString() + "|" + this.ServiceId.ToString();
            }
        }

        public long VisitId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool FeeIsWaived { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public Visit Visit { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public Service Service { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Service
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsHourly { get; set; }
        public bool IsMonthly { get; set; }

        //[Ignore]
        //public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }

        //[Ignore]
        //public ServicePrice CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Test Data:

```
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<MyNamespace.Visit>();
    db.DropAndCreateTable<MyNamespace.VisitService>();
    db.DropAndCreateTable<MyNamespace.Service>();

    var visitId = db.Insert(new MyNamespace.Visit {
        Date = DateTime.UtcNow, Notes = "Notes"}, selectIdentity: true);
    var serviceId = (int)db.Insert(new MyNamespace.Service { 
        ServiceTypeId = 1, Name = "Name"}, selectIdentity:true);
    db.Insert(new MyNamespace.VisitService {
        VisitId = visitId, ServiceId = serviceId, Quantity = 1});
}
```

Service Result:

```
http://localhost:{port}/visits/1/services.json
```

JSON Response:

```
{
    offset: 0,
    total: 1,
    results: [{
        serviceTypeId: 1,
        name: "Name",
        displayOrder: 0,
        isHourly: false,
        isMonthly: false,
        visitId: 1,
        serviceId: 1,
        quantity: 1,
        feeIsWaived: false
    }]
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters but the service and the DTOs are in different namespaces - MyNamespace.WebAPI and MyNamespace.DTO.  And because I'm "using" ServiceStack and MyNamespace.DTO in the service, my IJoin looks like IJoin<VisitService, MyNamespace.DTO.Service.  I don't see that you had to fully-qualify Service in your IJoin?  As I said, other services with almost identical code are working as expected - the only difference with this one (that I can see) is the name of the joined table...

Comment: @user2220004 fully-qualifying a type with a namespace or not has no difference in the compiled program - it's still referencing the same type. I've just used the types you've provided which I've added to an existing website and works as-is as seen in the example output above. It's very unlikely namespaces are the cause of your issues, AutoQuery only uses the name of the type to determine which table to query, never the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and making me go back for one more hard look at this.  Turns out one should never have a DTO/table called "Service" if one expects to write a "service" to go along with it.  I was referencing the DTO "VisitService" inside my ServiceStack service for visits called... VisitService.  I needed a couple more namespace qualifiers:  QueryBase<MyNamespace.DTO.VisitService, ServiceAtVisit>, IJoin<MyNamespace.DTO.VisitService, MyNamespace.DTO.Service>.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @mythz I name my tables with lowercase and then use Alias("tableName"). So the property name needs to be parentId instead of ParentId (this is preferred). Is there any other attribute I can add to make the property name ParentId instead of parentId?